Rubik's cube: Calculating how many times we need to repeat a sequence of moves to return it to its original state
Suppose you repeatedly perform the sequence of moves (U' and R) to an initially solved Rubik's cube until it is once again in the solved state. (So move the top face to the right, then the right face up and repeat).
I was expecting this to perhaps take a multiple of 16 repeats of the sequence to return back to its original state. Or at the very least a multiple of 4 repeats.
But it appears that the Rubik's cube requires $63$ repetitions of (U' and R) to return to the original state (so $126$ moves in total). Why is this? Is it a coincidence that this is 1 less than a power of 4?
Trying the same thing with the sequence of moves (U and R), it seems to take $105$ repetitions to return to the original state which makes me doubt that the $63$ we found was related to a power of 4 at all.
So I suppose the question that arises from this is:
In general, can we calculate how many times we will have to repeat a sequence of moves to return the cube back to its original state?
So an algorithm or function $F$ that inputs ordered, legal Rubik's moves and outputs how many times that this sequence of moves will need to be repeated to return the cube back to its original state. For example, $F(U,R) = 105$ and $F(U',R) = 63$

I believe you will find that all sequences are a multiple of 2 (for edge flip parity) and/or a multiple of 3 (for corner rotation parity).

You may be interested in reading about the Rubik's Cube Group (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Cube_group). Every operation you describe defines an element of that group, and what you're asking about is called the order of that element in group theoretic parlance. For instance (as mentioned in that article), the largest such order we can obtain is 1260 (achieved by RU^2D'BD').

In the Cubic Circular from 1982 https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/cubic3.htm#p34 this question is completely answered.

@0x5453 That is not true for all sequences, as the table linked in the previous comment proves. There are sequences of order 5 (for example a 5-cycle of edges that does not flip any of them).

To find the order of a permutation without just repeating the moves, you can do the moves just once, and figure out how all the stickers have moved in terms of cycles (e.g. if the sticker that was at location A has moved to location B, and the sticker that was at location B moved to location C, and the sticker that was at location C moved to location A, then you have a 3-cycle (A B C) ). Once you have the cycles, just take the lowest common multiple of their lengths to get the answer.

There are many software aids that can be used to study and mathematically understand the structures related to the Rubik's cube. Below I am using sage, then explain the results given by sage for the concrete sample case.

Code:
sage: move = "U' R"
sage: RubiksCube().move(move)
             ┌──────────────┐
             │  6    4    1 │
             │  7   top   2 │
             │ 33   36   38 │
┌────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────┬────────────┐
│ 17  18   3 │ 27   29   32 │ 48   34  35 │  9  10  11 │
│ 12 left 13 │ 20  front  5 │ 26 right 31 │ 45 rear 37 │
│ 14  15  16 │ 22   23    8 │ 25   28  30 │ 43  39  40 │
└────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────┴────────────┘
             │ 41   42   19 │
             │ 44 bottom 21 │
             │ 46   47   24 │
             └──────────────┘

sage: g = CubeGroup().move(move)[0]
sage: g
(1,6,33,9,17,27,35,11,3)(2,4,7,36,45,21,5)(8,38,43,19,32,30,25,48,24)(10,18,29,31,28,26,34)
sage: g.cycle_type()
[9, 9, 7, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

The move is the one considered, and it "acts" on the faces, more exactly on the individual stickers of the cube. One may think of a move alternatively as an operation on a cubic stone with stickers, and the stickers can be taken away and glued on an other place. Then from the initial state
sage: RubiksCube().move('')
             ┌──────────────┐
             │  1    2    3 │
             │  4   top   5 │
             │  6    7    8 │
┌────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────┬────────────┐
│  9  10  11 │ 17   18   19 │ 25   26  27 │ 33  34  35 │
│ 12 left 13 │ 20  front 21 │ 28 right 29 │ 36 rear 37 │
│ 14  15  16 │ 22   23   24 │ 30   31  32 │ 38  39  40 │
└────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────┴────────────┘
             │ 41   42   43 │
             │ 44 bottom 45 │
             │ 46   47   48 │
             └──────────────┘

Some places are changed. There are some changes to be observed. $1$ goes to $6$. Where does $6$ go? It is mapped to $33$, and so on. This data is written as a "cycle" $(1,6,33,\dots)$ and because there are finitely many stickers, the $1$ shows again in the list at some point. (To see this, it is clear that - if not the $1$, some other element in the list shows up again, then perform the moves in the cycle twice, and go back some steps to land on the $1$, so it shows up again.) In our case, sage gives us the cycle that involves the $1$, it is $ (1,6,33,9,17,27,35,11,3)$ as written in the line
sage: g
(1,6,33,9,17,27,35,11,3)(2,4,7,36,45,21,5)(8,38,43,19,32,30,25,48,24)(10,18,29,31,28,26,34)

So, regarding the places taken one by one by the sticker $1$, we have move for move the full "orbit" of the $1$:
$$
1\to 6\to 33\to 9\to 17\to 27\to 35\to 11\to 3\to 1\to\dots
$$
in a cyclic manner. Are these all the changes? No! It turns out that
$2$ is also involved, and its cycle is (2,4,7,36,45,21,5). Sage gives us the description of the move as a "product" of disjoint cycles, i.e. of cyclic moves that do not interfere.
To get the order of such a move, the cycle structure / type is relevant. The lengths of the individual cycles in the representations matter. In the above case for instance, to have a "neutral" action of the cycle that perverts the position of the $1$-sticker, which is (1,6,33,9,17,27,35,11,3), we have to apply it nine times, nine being the length of this "piece" in the representation of the move as a product of disjoint cycles. Doing so, also the other $9$-cycle has a neutral action on $8,38,\dots$. But the $7$-cycle is not killed, it is an other $7$-cycle. To make it also neutral, we have to repeat this furthermore $7$ times. So to have a completely neutral move, we have to repeat the move $7\cdot 9$ times. (In general it is the l.c.m. of the lengths of the involved cycles in the disjoint cycle decomposition.)

The same happens with the other move, too.
sage: RubiksCube().move("U R")
             ┌──────────────┐
             │ 38   36   33 │
             │  2   top   7 │
             │  1    4    6 │
┌────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────┬────────────┐
│ 48  34  35 │  9   10   11 │ 17   18   3 │ 27  29  32 │
│ 12 left 13 │ 20  front  5 │ 26 right 31 │ 45 rear 37 │
│ 14  15  16 │ 22   23    8 │ 25   28  30 │ 43  39  40 │
└────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────┴────────────┘
             │ 41   42   19 │
             │ 44 bottom 21 │
             │ 46   47   24 │
             └──────────────┘

sage: h = CubeGroup().move("U R")[0]
sage: h
(1,38,43,19,11,35,32,30,25,17,9,48,24,8,6)(2,36,45,21,5,7,4)(3,33,27)(10,34,29,31,28,26,18)
sage: h.cycle_type()
[15, 7, 7, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

The l.c.m. of the numbers in the last list is $3\cdot 5\cdot 7=105$.

Note: This tries to make explicit the argument in the comment of
Jaap Scherphuis.
